# JAR File is Viewed as Folder

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, maven, jar

I have a JAR-file in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of my project that is displayed as folder when I deploy my project to Tomcat.

I use Maven for getting JAR-files, Eclipse for building my app, and deploying to Tomcat.

Why is the JAR-file displayed as folder? I cannot use the file in this way, and Tomcat does not see it.

Comment: I need 15 reputation points for adding images :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Setting for child project (using wtp)]

This settings is for any child module if we have one parent maven project for him and we want to use wtp.

Eclipse gets changes from workspace.

For Example, we make changes in maven module and we don't need to install it and update dependencies for parent. Eclipse automatically updates the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Because if you use Eclipse Web Tools Platform for deploying, it puts artifacts, that you have in your Eclipse workspace as projects, exploded. It allows WTP to do some magic with replacing classes files in-place instead of repackaging whole artifact on every little change. For the container, it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks, Michal. I resolved this issue. I reconfigured all my Maven projects and it helped.